# Create an overflow at a given value

Tags: c++, c, position, overflow, counter

If a unsigned byte overflows it goes from 255 to 0 and vica versa -1 gives 255.

Would it be possible to have it overflow at for example 200?
Without using if statements.

Comment: No. What do you need this for?

Comment: Are you looking for modulo ?

Comment: I was looking for a way to keep track of a postion of a stepper. I use if statements now. So if larger than a fullrev subtract a fullrev. And vica versa. I was hoping there would be a quicker way.

Comment: Quicker?  Your if() is slow?

Answer (score 1):

Overflow is fairly simple:

```
unsigned int a = 150, b = 150;
a += b; // do an operation
a %= 200; // wrap it
```

However, with underflow, it's a bit harder (see orlp's answer for this).

To make it less error prone if you use this variable several times, in C++ with operator overloading, you can make a class that simulates an integer type which wraps after every operation with operator overloading.

Answer (score 1):

The modulo operator does what you want, with some trickery for negative values:

```
int wrap(int x, int n) {
    return x < 0 ? ((x % n) + n) % n : x % n;
}

// wrap(205, 200) == 5
// wrap(-1, 200) == 199
```

Comment: Thank you, i'm going to implement that. Great.

Comment: @MarcGlisse No, we want to make x positive. When `n - x` executes `x` is negative, so the result is positive.

Comment: Did you actually try `wrap(-1,200)`? x<0 so you are replacing -1 with 201, which is clearly not the same thing. I believe you want to do modulo first, then add n if still negative.

Comment: @MarcGlisse Woops. Fixed.

Comment: Using 2 modulos for the negative case seems excessive, especially if there is any performance concern...

Answer (score 0):

Unless your willing to learn assembly, such an action would be impossible for several reasons.

1. All the types like char, short, int, etc. are builtin and predefined by the parser.
2. 200 isnt a power of two; computer represent numbers in binary.

Note: The above is only true if you want implicit overflow; modulas lets you do explicit overflow.

Comment: Predefined by the parser? You surely meant to say that they are builtin, fundamental types?

Comment: I thought maybe im thinking to complex and there is a very simple math trick for this, but i geuess not.

Comment: I'd say the top-voted answer is probably what your looking for.